# Python Kivy: how to make execute a method after widgets Kivy file has loaded

Tags: python, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to build an interactive school timetable using Kivy. My logic is written inside Python and all layouts and the general estetic is written in Kivy files. I want to run a specific method right after the Kivy file has loaded so it changes the text of the buttons to display.

Here is how it looks after I start it:
[image: How it looks rn]

Here is how I want my app to look like after I start it:

[image: How it should look]

The names of days and lessons are in Polish .

Here is the code of planchart.py

```py
class Okienko(Button):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lessons = []

        f = open("/interaktywny_plan/classes.dat", "rb")
        pon = pickle.load(f)
        wto = pickle.load(f)
        sro = pickle.load(f)
        czw = pickle.load(f)
        pt = pickle.load(f)
        f.close()
        self.lessons.append(pon)
        self.lessons.append(wto)
        self.lessons.append(sro)
        self.lessons.append(czw)
        self.lessons.append(pt)

        self.lesson = ""
        self.sub_press = ""

    def on_release(self):
        self.text = self.lesson

    def on_press(self):
        self.text = self.sub_press

    def update_button(self):
        if self.name_ == "one_pon":
            self.lesson = self.lessons[0][0][0]
            self.sub_press = self.lessons[0][0][1] + "\n" + self.lessons[0][0][2]
        elif self.name_ == "two_pon":
            self.lesson = self.lessons[0][1][0]
            self.sub_press = self.lessons[0][1][1] + "\n" + self.lessons[0][1][2]
        elif self.name_ == "three_pon":
            self.lesson = self.lessons[0][2][0]
            self.sub_press = self.lessons[0][2][1] + "\n" + self.lessons[0][2][2]
        elif self.name_ == "four_pon":
            self.lesson = self.lessons[0][3][0]
            self.sub_press = self.lessons[0][3][1] + "\n" + self.lessons[0][3][2]

        .............
```

Here is the Kivy code:

```
<Okienko>:
    background_color: [.5, .9, 1, 1]
    halign: "center"
    size_hint: None, None
    font_size: 24
    size: 96, 96
    on_press: self.on_press()
    on_release: self.on_release()

<PlanChart>:
    cols: 11
    padding: 2
    Dzien:
        id: pon
        text: "Pon"
    Okienko:
        id: one_pon
        name_: "one_pon"
    Okienko:
        id: two_pon
        name_: "two_pon"
    Okienko:
        id: three_pon
        name_: "three_pon"
    Okienko:
        id: four_pon
        name_: "four_pon"
    Okienko:
        id: five_pon
        name_: "five_pon"

     ..............
```

I tried using `@mainthread` and putting `self.update_button()` in `__init__` but it would still start empty. I tried just putting `self.update_button()` in `__init__` but I would get `AtributeError` becouse the Kivy file was not loaded. After that I read about `Clock` module but I couldn't figure how to use it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Clock`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html) module to schedule a method call for *after* the Kivy file is loaded:

```py
from kivy.clock import Clock
Clock.schedule_once(self.update_button, .1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I placed it in the end of `__init__` and added `(self, *args)` to update_button class and it works perfectly!

Comment: Option 2: same as above but without `, .1`. This will call the callback "as soon as possible (usually next frame.)" ([source](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html)). Which option is better?

Comment: Option 3: add an `id: foo` under `<Okienko>:` and in build() of your App class, call something like `self.screen.ids.foo.update_button()`.

Comment: Its faster and more good-looking without the `, .1` of course.;o) I add it, just to point its existence (if someone wasn't familiar with it)..